# Docker EXPOSE a port only to bridge

Tags: docker

I want to map container port only to internal docker bridge (172.17.0.*)
If it's possible ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All ports between containers on the same docker network are accessible to each other. There is no need to expose ports, expose is only needed to document the port by the image creator for the admin running the container. Publishing ports is only needed to make a specific port available outside of the host. For your requirement, there's nothing to do, it's the default behavior.